# Can A be singular?

Tags: matrices, inverse

Let $A\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ satisfy
$$A^{2}+A+I=0 $$ Can A be singular?

So I have:
$$
(A-I)(A^{2}+A+I)=0\\
A^{3} = I
\\
(\det A^{3}) = \det(I)
\\
(\det A)^{3} = 1\\
\det A\neq 0
$$
So $A$ is not singular.

Is this correct the way I've done this?

Comment: Yes this is perfect!

Comment: That's a good way of doing it yes :). Or you can say that eigenvalues of A are roots of $A^2 +A+1$ , hence 0 cannot be an eigenvalue

Comment: Cayley-Hamilton is such a big hammer to wield for problems such as these...

Comment: You are correct. Sorry about that, I did not see it.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, your solution is correct! Equivalently $A^2+A+I=0$ implies that $$A(-A-I)=I$$ and therefore $A$ is invertible and $-A-I$ is it's inverse, i.e. $A^{-1}=-A-I$.

Comment: Note that $A^2=-A-I$ from the original equation. From $A^3=I$ in the question we also get $A^{-1}=A^2$ directly.